# Create desktop shortcut for Safari to a specific web - on MacOS

Tags: macos, bash, script, macbook, url

I'm trying to create a desktop shortcut for Safari that will lead to a specific website when the users will use it. Trying for hours but with no success. Can someone help please?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried & why didn't it work? You have to present your research to save people duplicating effort.

Comment: the answer given by bce is how i do it

Answer (score 1):

If you highlight the URL and then drag-and-drop it onto your desktop, that should create a shortcut link for you.